# Why is the author info box on question posts now coloured blue?

Tags: support, design, user-interface

I’ve noticed this change and not sure if I like it aesthetically, but what does it semantically signify?

Comment: @Makyen idts… is it basically just a change of colour palettes with no semantic significance?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, yes, there's no intent to add additional semantic significance.

Comment: @Seekinganswers it's like re-painting a whole house. It's meant to make it more appealing to those living inside and for guests, and can make actual difference, e.g. it might make important things stand out more, i.e. easier to see/find them. That said, in SE case it was a total disaster, but at least they appear to actually try and improve it.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry that seems like a strong answer to this question to me.

Comment: Yes, the answer to "did the colours change?" is the explanation of "we changed the colours".